# adding rtmp module to nginx after it is already configured

Tags: nginx, module, configuration, server, rtmp

I configured rtmp with http and when I try to add the directive for RTMP in my .conf file, the server throws an error. 
I went in and checked the sbin directory for the modules added. Turns out RTMP was not one of them. 
I have downloaded the nginx-rtmp-module-1.1.7 which I want to add to nginx and compile it. I am not sure how to proceed with it.